# Sass Compass multiple themes ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, sass

I have a rails app that is a sort of CMS and i alow users to create their own version of the applicaton on a sub domain.

I also want to let them style their app version the way they want but changing a few fields or small config file.

I was hoping to be able to use sass and compass and be able to let users change varialbes for there own style.

How can i do this ?  is it possible as saas needs to be compiled to css when varialbes are changed.  i think?

Is there a better way ?

thanks alot 
richard moss

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use Sass functions to access the outside environment; see [the Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html) for details. Before you do this, make sure you'll be properly caching your stylesheets so that they don't need to be regenerated for every request.